# Redirects for both paths and posts in the path

Tags: redirects, regex

I rarely need to do redirects and when I do they're usually simple. This time I'm trying to do something a little more advanced and I'm stumped. Regex is hard :)

This is a WordPress site and I'm using the Redirection plugin by John Godley.

I have a bunch of posts grouped by districts. I need to redirect both the landing pages for those districts:

```
(landing page) 

foo.com/listing/old-district/ -> foo.com/new-district/
```

And all posts within those districts:

```
(posts in those districts)

foo.com/listing/old-district/post1 -> foo.com/new-district/post1
foo.com/listing/old-district/post2 -> foo.com/new-district/post2
etc
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> This is a WordPress site and I'm using the Redirection plugin by John Godley.

There is an example on the [Plugin's "Redirect Regular Expressions" page](https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/) that appears to do exactly what you need.

For example, your "source URL" would be:

```
/listing/old-district/(.*)
```

and corresponding "Target URL" would be:

```
/new-district/$1
```

The pattern `(.*)` captures anything (including *nothing*) that might follow `/listing/old-district/`. `$1` in the target URL is a backreference that contains whatever has been captured from the "source URL" (if anything).

In more detail, the `.` (dot) matches any character (except newlines) and the `*` is a *quantifier* that states we should match 0 or more of the preceding pattern (in this case, just a single character).

Comment: Thanks MrWhite, as it turns out I was getting mighty close to just that :) I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.